# How to paste into another directory using pdftotext.exe in R studio?

Tags: r

This is my code for converting .pdf into .txt file to text mining purpose. Note that I used a pdftotext.exe to convert .pdf to .txt file.

```
dest <-"C:/Users/Unimas/Documents/R/Converted into text file/all files"
pdffiles <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "pdf",  full.names = TRUE)
test <- lapply(pdffiles, function(i) system(paste('"D:/External_Software/XpdfReader-win64/xpdf-tools-win-4.00/bin64/pdftotext.exe"', 
                                     paste0('"', i, '"')), wait = FALSE) )
```

The problem is I wanted to change the converted .txt file into another directory. How to do that?

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
library(tools)
src <-"C:/source/dir"
pdffiles <- list.files(path = src, pattern = "pdf",  full.names = TRUE)
test <- lapply(pdffiles, function(i) system(paste('"pdftotext.exe"', 
paste0('"', i, '"'), paste0('"C:/path/to/some/out/folder/', basename(file_path_sans_ext(i)), '.txt"')), wait = FALSE) )
```

Explanation

- the output file is moved directly via the second parameter of [pdftotext](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/pdftotext.htm)
- the path and the extension is stripped off the input file name using `basename` and `tools::file_path_sans_ext`, the destination folder is prefixed and `.txt"` is appended
- you may want to add `pdftotext.exe` to your System `PATH`